# Horizontal Top Menu and Sitemap

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to pick up some CSS as I try to make temporary styling for this site while they find their stylesheet: http://faq.travelbelize.org/travel_belize

The priority is to get the menu and sitemap cleaned up (both have the class of "menu"), but I'm having trouble making them display horizontally.

I've tried:

```
.menu {
display: inline
list-style-type: none
}
```

Do I need to be more specific with my CSS selector? I've also tried it with .menu ul li without luck.
I've also played with padding, margins, display: list-item, and floats without luck.

Comment: Show your markup, please

Comment: It is very rare that you would want to change an element's display to `inline`.  More often than not, `inline-block` is what you're looking for.

Comment: Markup: view-source:http://faq.travelbelize.org/travel_belize

I tried inline-block as well. I'm just not getting the selectors right for top and bottom menus, social icons, and search form. Isn't there a way to get all of them in a line?